# Why is the program showing me "was not declared in this scope"?

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>   
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void initialize(int& lc, int list[]);
void copyText(ifstream& intext, ofstream& outtext, char& ch,
              int list[]);
void writeTotal(ofstream& outtext, int lc, int list[]);

int main()
{
  //Step 1; Declare variables
    int lineCount;
    int letterCount[26];
    char ch;
    ifstream infile; 
    ofstream outfile; 

  // Tell User what the program is doing     
    cout << "\nReads a text paragraph from testin.txt file then counts "
         << "lines and letters and outputs to textout.txt file.\n\n";

  // Open input and output files
    infile.open("textin.txt");                      //Step 2

    if (infile)                                     //Step 3 
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the input file." 
             << endl;
        return 1;
    }

  // Process Data and send data to output file    
    cout << "\n\n\t *** Processing Input File Data and Creating" 
         << "Output File ***\n\n";

    outfile.open("textout.txt");                    //Step 4

    initialize(lineCount, letterCount);             //Step 5

    infile.get(ch);                                 //Step 6

    while (infile)                                  //Step 7
    {
        copyText(infile, outfile, ch, letterCount); //Step 7.1
        lineCount++;                                 //Step 7.2  
        infile.get(ch);                             //Step 7.3
    }

    writeTotal(outfile, lineCount, letterCount);    //Step 8

  // Close files
    infile.close();                                 //Step 9
    outfile.close();                                //Step 9  

   // Holdscreen for those systems that need it.
    cout << "\n\n\tPress a Character and Press Enter to Exit! ";
    cin >> ch;

    return 0;
}

void initialize(int& lc, int list[])
{
    int j;
    lc = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        list[j] = 0;
} //end initialize

void copyText(ifstream& intext, ofstream& outtext, char& ch,
              int list[])
{
    while (ch != '\n')      //process the entire line
    {
        outtext << ch;      //output the character


    characterCount(ch, list);   //call the function 
                                    //character count
        intext.get(ch);     //read the next character
    }
    outtext << ch;          //output the newline character
} //end copyText

void characterCount(char ch, int list[])
{
    int index;

    ch = toupper(ch);                       //Step a

    index = static_cast<int>(ch)
            - static_cast<int>('A');        //Step b

    if (0 <= index && index < 26)           //Step c
        list[index]++;
} //end characterCount

void writeTotal(ofstream& outtext, int lc, int list[])
{
    int index;

    outtext << endl << endl;
    cout << "The number of lines = " << lc << endl;  

    for (index = 0; index < 26; index++)
        outtext << static_cast<char>(index + static_cast<int>('A'))
                << " count = " << list[index] << endl;
} //end writeTotal
```

I am executing/debugging this code. It gives me "characterCount not declared" error (line 82:5). I have searched through Google but found no help.
I have also made sure that I am using all the correct #include functions. I have tried declaring this variable but found no success. Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to declare `void characterCount(char ch, int list[]);` at the top of your file, like you've done for the other functions.

Comment: ... or put the entire function before anything that calls it.